# Twilio REST API - Server error

Tags: php, api, sms, sms-gateway, twilio

I am getting the following error when I try to send a SMS using the Twilio REST API.

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

Code:

```
require("Services/Twilio.php");

$account_sid = "ACD123456789"; // Your Twilio account sid
$auth_token = "ACD123456789"; // Your Twilio auth token

$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);
$message = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
  '+1415599XXXX', // From a Twilio number in your account
  '+1609531XXXX', // Text any number
  "Hello world!"
);

print $message->sid;
```

Comment: Hi, This part of the code looks fine. Can you check that your file begins with `<?php`? Also, a 500 server error means that there should be a log file explaining the error somewhere - see if you can find it and read the message there.

Comment: After enabling error log i found the mobile number i have been using is unverified. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have JSON and cURL enabled in your PHP hosting environment?  This is what I had to do to get the [Twilio PHP helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) working on Joyent's shared servers:

http://carter.rabasa.com/2012/02/10/getting-json-and-curl-enabled-in-php-on-joyent-shared-servers/

You can also email help@twilio.com for support if this doesn't resolve your problem.